# How to parse JSON in Swift 4 when root element is an array?

Tags: json, swift, swift4

Some context: [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/93gpho/easiest_way_to_make_many_similar_views/)

I have two structs. One is called bio that has fields such as name, bio, spotifyURL, etc. The other struct is called Artists which has one field, bios, an array of bio.

My JSON file has an array as the root element, with two elements (artists) inside it. The identifiers of the elements match up with the identifiers of the fields in the structs.

When I call:

```
let bioArray = try
   JSONDecoder().decode(Artists.self, from: data)
```

bioArray.bios is an empty array. Shouldn't this populate the array? The data was retrieved successfully, decode() just isn't doing what I think it should be doing. Thanks

EDIT: Wow, I fixed it. In Artists I had:

```
let bios:[bio] = []
```

I changed it to:

```
let bios:[bio]
```

and now it works...

Comment: It's worth posting the solution as an answer. If you leave it as an edit to the question, your question will remain unanswered. Posting it as an answer and then accepting it will show it has been answered.

Comment: udpate your finding as answer so that other could take help from this.

Comment: You should be able to post the question and provide the answer to it.
If you scroll down, you should be able to spot it. "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style"

Comment: @MartinR yeah it is the same problem. I guess I didn't realize at the time for some reason. Nice find

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I fixed it. In Artists I had:

```
let bios:[bio] = []
```

I changed it to:

```
let bios:[bio]
```

and now it works...

The answer is in the duplicate link but I'll put it here too:

To fix this either remove the initialization (like I did) or change the *let* to *var*.